# get side panel info - wikipedia

Tags: python, wikipedia

I am looking for a way to get an information from a side panel of wikipedia website, example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix
(the panel on the right)

I was trying using this:

```
import wikipedia
xx = wikipedia.page("Netlix")
xx.title
print(xx.content)
```

It does provide the whole page content - besides side panel.

I was trying to avoid BeautifulSoup package, but I am not sure if it's possible. Any ideas?

Comment: As this is a package specific issue you might have a better chance of getting a response for the functionality you wish by filing an issue at the [project's issue tracker](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia/issues).

Comment: The wikipedia python package and even the API has a lot of missing features. I don't think what you are trying to do is possible without an alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

This is how to approach the problem with BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url_wiki = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix'
table_class = "infobox vcard"
response = requests.get(url_wiki)

# parse data from the html into a beautifulsoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
side_panel = soup.find('table', {'class': "infobox"})

df = pd.read_html(str(side_panel))
# convert list to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0])
print(df)
```